# Is there a way to see when a users last activity was in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

Is there a way to see when a user's or service_account's last activity was?
This would help with user and account audits. For example, in AWS there is an IAM report that tells you
"password_last_used"
and
"access_key_1_last_used_date".

Note: this is for bigquery itself, not the data I have loaded into BQ.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [BigQuery Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/) to check for the most recent log entry tagged to a specific user. 
e.g.

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="some.user@mycompany.com"
```

You could also [export the audit logs back into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/) to make it easier to query the information for a specific user.